# Use of unassigned local variable "SHELLEXECUTEINFO"

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, compiler-errors

Hello everyone got an error on debugging my application written in c#
this is the error:

**Use of unassigned local variable "SHELLEXECUTEINFO"**

THIS IS THE ERROR LINE cbSize = Marshal.SizeOf(sHELLEXECUTEINFO),

i dont know why i get this error or how to correct it.

```
private bool PWOLaunch(int iTab)
    {
        string pWOLocation = Settings.Default.PWOLocation;
        if (!File.Exists(pWOLocation))
        {
            this.openFileDialog1.ShowDialog();
            pWOLocation = this.openFileDialog1.FileName;
            if (!pWOLocation.Contains("PWO.exe"))
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Failed to Locate file: PWO.exe\nThis bot is only for Pokemon World Online!");
                return false;
            }
            if (pWOLocation.Contains("PWO.exe"))
            {
                Settings.Default.PWOLocation = pWOLocation;
                Settings.Default.Save();
            }
        }
        Form1.PROCESS_INFORMATION pROCESSINFORMATION = new Form1.PROCESS_INFORMATION();
        Form1.STARTUPINFO sTARTUPINFO = new Form1.STARTUPINFO();
        Form1.SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES sECURITYATTRIBUTE = new Form1.SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES();
        Form1.SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES sECURITYATTRIBUTE1 = new Form1.SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES();
        Form1.SHELLEXECUTEINFO sHELLEXECUTEINFO = new Form1.SHELLEXECUTEINFO()
        {
            cbSize = Marshal.SizeOf(sHELLEXECUTEINFO),
            lpFile = pWOLocation,
            nShow = 1,
            lpVerb = "runas",
            fMask = 64
        };
        if (!Form1.CreateProcess(pWOLocation, null, ref sECURITYATTRIBUTE, ref sECURITYATTRIBUTE1, false, 32, IntPtr.Zero, null, ref sTARTUPINFO, out pROCESSINFORMATION))
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Failed to Launch file: PWO.exe");
            return false;
        }
        StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder("ThunderRT6FormDC");
        IntPtr zero = IntPtr.Zero;
        while (zero == IntPtr.Zero)
        {
            zero = this.FindProcessWindow(stringBuilder, pROCESSINFORMATION.dwProcessId);
        }
        if (!this.EmbedGame(zero, iTab))
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Failed to launch game into bot");
        }
        this.gameWindowHandles[iTab] = zero;
        this.gameProcesshandles[iTab] = pROCESSINFORMATION.dwProcessId;
        this.gameBotHandles[iTab] = IntPtr.Zero;
        this.gameLogHandles[iTab] = IntPtr.Zero;
        Form1.ShowWindow(this.gameWindowHandles[1], 0);
        this.launchAllToolStripMenuItem.Text = "Restart Game";
        return true;
    }
```

Comment: sorry for the bad displaying i am new here and i dont know how to edit me question....

Comment: There is an `edit` button under your question. Welcome to Stack Overflow by the way. You can start to learn this site reading [FAQ], [ask] and [help]

Comment: In Marshal.SizeOf you are using the field, move the assignment out.

Comment: Most of the code shown is unrelated to the problem. That makes it harder than necessary to help. I could reduce all of this to one line.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your initializer is using the variable before it is initialized.  A common chicken-and-egg problem with initializers.  You could just use the other overload:

```
    Form1.SHELLEXECUTEINFO sHELLEXECUTEINFO = new Form1.SHELLEXECUTEINFO()
    {
        cbSize = Marshal.SizeOf(typeof(Form1.SHELLEXECUTEINFO)),
        lpFile = pWOLocation,
        // etc...
    };
```

Or the more general solution:

```
    Form1.SHELLEXECUTEINFO sHELLEXECUTEINFO = new Form1.SHELLEXECUTEINFO()
    {
        lpFile = pWOLocation,
        // etc...
    };
    sHELLEXECUTEINFO.cbSize = Marshal.SizeOf(sHELLEXECUTEINFO));
```

Ask somebody to review your code btw.

Answer (score 0):

The C# compiler does not allow the use of uninitialized variables. Looks like you didn't initialize your `sHELLEXECUTEINFO` variable before you use it.

Comment: that was fast thanks for the fast answer.
But how to initialize it?

Comment: @user3328787 But please reformat your code. So we can help your better.